# $\Sigma_1 \cup \Sigma_2$ has a model

Tags: logic, model-theory

Let $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$ be sets of $L$-sentences such that no symbol of $L$ occurs in both $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$. Suppose $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$ have infinite models. Then $\Sigma_1 \cup \Sigma_2$ has a model.

We have some facts about back and forth systems and Vaught's test, and Löwenheim-Skolem's theorem, and by that last one I can say that $\Sigma_1, \Sigma_2$ have models of cardinality equal to the cardinality of $L$, but I don't know where to go from there. For instance, we don't necessarily want to show that $\Sigma_1 \cup \Sigma_2$ is complete, so things like Vaught's test seem irrelevant.

Does this just follow from a slick argument about compactness?

Comment: (1) Are you treating equality as a primitive concept? (2) Is Gödel's completeness theorem available?

Comment: So, for instance, what if you take a unary operator $U$ and let the sentence $\forall x Ux$ this can certainly be true in a model of $\Sigma_1$, but in the union it is not true in general, since no model of $\Sigma_2$ has any restrictions based on $U$. Would "closing it under Skolem functions" change that? I don't quite know what that means.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, we do have the completeness/compactness theorems available. And equality is not considered part of the language. This is all within predicate logic, and I think this is what you mean by equality being primitive.

Comment: I asked because it is possible to formulate predicate calculus such that equality is not a logical concept, but one that a theory has to define itself with appropriate proper axioms if it needs it. (For example, Mendelson develops set theory with $a=b$ being an abbreviation for $\forall x.x\in a\leftrightarrow x\in b$).

Comment: Ah. Well this is a first course in mathematical logic, so we are sticking to what one might perhaps call the standard predicate logic.

Comment: My point is that while the choice in your course is by all means a common and respectable one, it probably cannot be said to be _the_ standard one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the theories have infinite models, you can find a $\kappa$ large enough that both theories have models of size $\kappa$. What happens if you take two such models, one from each theory, and simply identify the domains with each other?

Answer (score 5):

Let $M_1$ and $M_2$ be a models of $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$. By Skolem-Löwenheim we can assume without loss of generality that $M_1$ and $M_2$ have the same cardinality. And then, again without loss of generality, we can assume that they have *the same set of individuals* and just come with different interpretations of their respective parts of the language ...